# Boot from one drive, and run Windows from another

Tags: boot, bios, boot-partition, nvme

So... I have an old HP Z600 workstation which is pretty awesome with dual Xeons and 48GB of ECC ram. My problem is that storage speed is a huge bottleneck. Due to its age the motherboard and BIOS only support SATA II (3 GB/s) which limits the speed of a SSD. I found a Marvel SATA III PCIe controller which works, but the BIOS will only allocate one lane, so it's still limited to about 4 GB/s. I have the latest BIOS and the BIOS is encrypted so none of the 3rd party BIOS hackers have had any success at updating it and adding new functionality.

So... I took a chance and bought a Samsung 970 NVMe M2 drive and a PCIe adapter knowing that I would probably not be able to boot from it, and I was correct. Once Windows starts and loads its own NVMe driver though, it recognizes the drive just fine. And *WOW is it A LOT faster*. (A minimum of 4 times faster, up to 10 times, depending on which benchmark you look at.)

So... The machine also includes a couple of WD HDDs which are plugged into the motherboard's SATA II ports. **I was hoping to find a way to get the machine to start its boot from a HDD, load the bare minimum necessary to recognize the NVMe drive, then switch over and finish booting, and more importantly, run Windows from the NVMe drive.**

So far I've put a clone of the "System Reserved" partition at the beginning of the first hard disk (on first SATA port on motherboard) and set it to primary and active.  I've done bootrec /fixmbr and /fixboot, made a boot.ini with an entry pointing to windows on the NVMe, and quite a few other things without success.  I'm quite good with computers but this is uncharted territory for me. (never had the need before now)

So is this do-able? Could someone perhaps give me a summary of how it might be accomplished and steer me towards some documentation with the details?  Or perhaps a workaround to achieve similar results?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) - commonly used as the bootloader for Linux Distributions but also supports Windows with no problems (indeed, it is often used to dual boot Windows and Linux).

Use the guide below to install it on your **HDD**. After step 6 you should see the installer automatically identify and list your Windows install on the NVME drive.

The boot process will then be `BIOS/POST ---> Grub on the HDD ---> Pass off to NVME boot`

[Installing GRUB from Windows](https://www.aioboot.com/en/install-grub2-from-windows/)